# need to schedule a cron php to check webpage loading

Tags: php, magento, caching, curl, cron

**Problem:** Webpage loading fails sometimes randomly, sometime partial(no css, no image just raw html, both admin and frontend).

**Temporary Solution we had is to ** delete/flush cache, its a magento website, and it works.

**What I'm trying to do** is to schedule a cron job, which will check the page loading, it will be checking css/images loading. if it finds *problem* it will flush cache and email or make a log entry.

Can you guide me how I can detect by running a server side script.

Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opted for another solution, just analysed the size of cache at which site crashes and scheduled a cron to flush. Its working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever considered WebPageTest? (http://www.webpagetest.org/).
I have a site that uses WPT (http://www.fasttimes.com/) that has cron jobs to initialize tests for sites.  It returns JSON data you can parse and see what's working and what's failing